# How to implement content security policy in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, security, seo, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to know how to implement CSP on Magento 2 with GTM. 
The site has multiple stores. Tried to google but was unable to find any concrete result. 
[Implimenting a Content Security Policy Magento 1.9.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146700/implimenting-a-content-security-policy-magento-1-9-x)

Comment: have you implement this?

Comment: @kimnana not yet.

Comment: For now i have added this in .htaccess . but still finding for best solution

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add CSP by modifying Magento (2.2.11) **Configuration > General > Web > Upgrade Insecure Requests**. I tested using https://securityheaders.com/